# Android Studio 0.8.14: Duplicate files during packaging of APK

Tags: android, gradle, apk, packing

When trying to build my app using Android Studio 0.8.14, I get the following errors:

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\pc2_2\Desktop\DOSTTracker\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE
    Origin 1: C:\Users\pc2_2\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.4.4\e2ff13c3de2f5a2ab2449a3dace2b0d1c37bd8ee\jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
    Origin 2: C:\Users\pc2_2\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.4.4\d3dad1a494f94579fca4b6a1142fb15fb68f0b2f\jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File 1: C:\Users\pc2_2\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.4.4\e2ff13c3de2f5a2ab2449a3dace2b0d1c37bd8ee\jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\pc2_2\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.4.4\e2ff13c3de2f5a2ab2449a3dace2b0d1c37bd8ee\jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.ajwcc.locationtracker"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

I already added the packagingOptions as suggested by Android Studio and other SO posts, but I am still getting the error. What am I missing?

Comment: why do you have 2 android blocks? have you tried to put all in one block?

Comment: @ligi Yes, I have tried to put them all in one block. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was referencing this app as a dependency from another app, and was building the other app. I had to include the packagingOptions in the build.gradle file of the other app as well.